# SignalR .NET Client connecting to Azure SignalR Service in a Blazor .NET Core 3 application

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I'm trying to make a connection between my ASP.NET Core 3.0 Blazor (server-side) application and the Azure SignalR Service. I'll end up injecting my SignalR client (service) in to a few Blazor components so they'll update my UI/DOM in realtime.

My issue is that I'm receiving the following message when I call my `.StartAsync()` method on the hub connection:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).

#### BootstrapSignalRClient.cs

This file loads my configuration for the SignalR Service including the URL, connection string, key, method name, and hub name. These settings are captured in the static class `SignalRServiceConfiguration` and used later.

```
public static class BootstrapSignalRClient
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSignalRServiceClient(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        SignalRServiceConfiguration signalRServiceConfiguration = new SignalRServiceConfiguration();
        configuration.Bind(nameof(SignalRServiceConfiguration), signalRServiceConfiguration);

        services.AddSingleton(signalRServiceConfiguration);
        services.AddSingleton<ISignalRClient, SignalRClient>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

#### SignalRServiceConfiguration.cs

```
public class SignalRServiceConfiguration
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string HubName { get; set; }
}
```

#### SignalRClient.cs

```
public class SignalRClient : ISignalRClient
{
    public delegate void ReceiveMessage(string message);
    public event ReceiveMessage ReceiveMessageEvent;

    private HubConnection hubConnection;

    public SignalRClient(SignalRServiceConfiguration signalRConfig)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(signalRConfig.Url + signalRConfig.HubName)
            .Build();            
    }

    public async Task<string> StartListening(string id)
    {
        // Register listener for a specific id
        hubConnection.On<string>(id, (message) => 
        {
            if (ReceiveMessageEvent != null)
            {
                ReceiveMessageEvent.Invoke(message);
            }
        });

        try
        {
            // Start the SignalR Service connection
            await hubConnection.StartAsync(); //<---I get an exception here
            return hubConnection.State.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }            
    }

    private void ReceiveMessage(string message)
    {
        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);
    }
}
```

I have experience using SignalR with .NET Core where you add it so the `Startup.cs` file using `.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR()` and map a hub in the app config and doing it this way requires certain 'configuration' parameters to be established (i.e. connection string).

Given my situation, where does `HubConnectionBuilder` get the connection string or a key to authenticate to the SignalR Service?

Is it possible the 404 message is a result of the missing key/connection string?

Comment: `.WithUrl(signalRConfig.Url + signalRConfig.HubName)` Can you verify this is resulting in the correct Url? (By breakpoint or logging?)

Comment: I found it useful to have the base Uri as `Uri` and construct the complete one via [Uri(Uri, string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Uri__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_)

Comment: interestingly it was a 'red herring' and had nothing to do with the 404.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay so it turns out the documentation is lacking a key piece of information here. If you're using the .NET SignalR Client connecting to the Azure SignalR Service, you need to request a JWT token and present it when creating the hub connection.

If you need to authenticate on behalf of a user you can use [this example.](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/blob/master/samples/Serverless/ClientHandler.cs#L25)

Otherwise, you can set up a "/negotiate" endpoint using a web API such as an Azure Function to retrive a JWT token and client URL for you; this is what I ended up doing for my use case. Information about creating an Azure Function to get your JWT token and URL can be found [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service#using-signalr-service-with-azure-functions)

I created a class to hold these two values as such:

#### SignalRConnectionInfo.cs

```
public class SignalRConnectionInfo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accessToken")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

I also created a method inside my `SignalRService` to handle the interaction with the web API's "/negotiate" endpoint in Azure, the instantiation of the hub connection, and the use of an event + delegate for receiving messages as follows:

#### SignalRClient.cs

```
public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    SignalRConnectionInfo signalRConnectionInfo;
    signalRConnectionInfo = await functionsClient.GetDataAsync<SignalRConnectionInfo>(FunctionsClientConstants.SignalR);

    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(signalRConnectionInfo.Url, options =>
        {
           options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(signalRConnectionInfo.AccessToken);
        })
        .Build();
}
```

The `functionsClient` is simply a strongly typed `HttpClient` pre-configured with a base URL and the `FunctionsClientConstants.SignalR` is a static class with the "/negotiate" path which is appended to the base URL.

Once I had this all set up I called the `await hubConnection.StartAsync();` and it "connected"!

After all this I set up a static `ReceiveMessage` event and a delegate as follows (in the same `SignalRClient.cs`):

```
public delegate void ReceiveMessage(string message);
public static event ReceiveMessage ReceiveMessageEvent;
```

Lastly, I implemented the `ReceiveMessage` delegate:

```
await signalRClient.InitializeAsync(); //<---called from another method

private async Task StartReceiving()
{
    SignalRStatus = await signalRClient.ReceiveReservationResponse(Response.ReservationId);
    logger.LogInformation($"SignalR Status is: {SignalRStatus}");

    // Register event handler for static delegate
    SignalRClient.ReceiveMessageEvent += signalRClient_receiveMessageEvent;
}

private async void signalRClient_receiveMessageEvent(string response)
{
    logger.LogInformation($"Received SignalR mesage: {response}");
    signalRReservationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignalRReservationResponse>(response);
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); //<---used by Blazor (server-side)
}
```

I've provided documentation updates back to the Azure SignalR Service team and sure hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Update: the sample with the serverless sample [is deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/master/samples/Serverless) for the management SDK ([sample](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/blob/master/samples/Management)). The management SDK uses a negotiation server.

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer

Comment: I know, but I couldn't add it as comment - missing the required points :(